# How making <select> field pre-filled in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Try to keep value selected when edit the form but below code select only last inserted value kindly guide

```
           <select class="form-control" name="category">
               <option value disabled selected>--Select Category Name--</option>
               <?php $items = job_category::all(); ?>
               @foreach ($items as $item) 
               <?php $cat_job= job::Where(['cat_id'=>$item->id])->first(); 
                  ?>
                       
               <option value="{{ $item->id }}" selected >{{ $item->category }}</option>
               
               @endforeach
           </select>
```

Comment: you are setting them all as selected, you would need a conditional in there to decide which one to set as selected

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Code will help you
You just make if condition in your option tag

```
<option value="{{ $item->id }}" @if($item->category == "HR") selected @endif >{{ $item->category }}</option>
```